# Store the values of an element upon clicking on a link to a different page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been trying very hard to figure out how to store the value of the element (image) to a different page (anything.php) when someone clicks on a link.

HTML:

```html
<div class="slide-body" data-group="slide">

  <img src="assets/img/slide-1.jpg" name="Image 1">

  <div class="caption add-box" data-animate="slideAppearRightToLeft">
    <a href="#" class="butn btn btn-default">Add</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, what I want to do is click on "Add" and then save the "name" of the image to a different file called "file-2.php". After doing that, I also want to be able to call that value from "file-2.php" when needed.

Please suggest any solution that can accomplish this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your server-side codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query string to pass information to a PHP page using a link. For example:

```
<div class="slide-body" data-group="slide">

  <img src="assets/img/slide-1.jpg" name="Image 1">

  <div class="caption add-box" data-animate="slideAppearRightToLeft">
    <a href="file-2.php?imageName=myImageName" class="butn btn btn-default">Add</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in your PHP you can access `$_GET['imageName']` and it will return `'myImageName'`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, is there any possible way to replace the "myImageName" to the actual name of the image? For eg, here the "name" of images is "Image 1". And maybe the name of my next image will be "Image 2" and so on. So, how can I get a different name for differen image and also be able to store them like before. Maybe using a PHP snippet to call the "name" property of the image will do?

Answer (score 0):

Data is not save in "pages".
It can be saved in session, localstorage, cookies ... and, commonly, databases.

So the first question is: where should be the best place to store the data?

This depends strictly from the behavior of each scope of your application.

So in this case for example, are the data volatile or should be retrieved many times from many different devices? You want to keep track of the data of your users or will the data reside only in the user device?

Anyway, your file_that_receive_data.php will act as a controller and take care of that. This file can also be the same where data is presented, that depending on the request does a job or another.

Your php file will receive data through a request, that can be GET or POST type. Commonly the GET method is used to retrieve the data and the POST method to send data to it.

so in a very simple way (security concerns and various sanitizing/validations might taken into account) your php will have:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['image'])){
$image_path = $_POST['image'];
// an image has been sent so then based on you logic will be stored somewhere
echo 'ok';
die();
}elseif(isset($get['whatever'])){
// a GET request have been done with whatever parameter (if you have to show only current user selection of images you'll need any kind of descriptor for him, for example an id that came with your image before?)
} ?>
```

Next you need the frontend to work and in this case I would use ajax for example so:

```
<div class="slide-body" data-group="slide">
  <img src="assets/img/slide-1.jpg" name="Image 1">
  <div class="caption add-box" data-animate="slideAppearRightToLeft">
    <a href="#" class="butn btn btn-default" data-image="assets/img/slide-1.jpg">Add</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  // jquery need to be loaded before this point
  $('.butn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var imagepath = $(this).data('image');
    $.ajax({
      url: '/path/to/your/file_that_receive_data.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {'image':imagepath},
      success: function(data){
        if(data.length && data === 'ok'){
          alert('Image saved!');
        }else{
          alert('some sort of soft managed error or alert');
        }
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('some technical error occurred');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The data, the "name" property of Image, is to be stored in sessions. For eg, when a user clicks on "Add" link, the **name** of the image will store in session (on the same page maybe), then the user clicks on another link which **again saves** the name of the next image. So, in this manner, multiple names (data) will be stored in a session. After that, I want to be able to call those stored "names" from a different page.